# Full text search using Mongoid

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

Is there a way to use MongoDB (v 2.4)'s full text search feature via Mongoid? I tried the answer from [google group link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongoid/hJRbaNMy6w4/PEolIR2SJ2oJ) but kept on getting the following error.

In one tab, I started mongod as such: `~$ mongod --setParameter textSearchEnabled=true`
The line that caused the error:
`Article.mongo_session.command({:text => {:search => 'Ruby'}})`

It would be great if someone could point out a way to execute MongoDB `runCommand` within Ruby, so that I could directly run the command `db.collection.runCommand( "text", { search: <string> })`

```
failed with error 13111: "exception: wrong type for field (text) 3 != 2"

See https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/docs/errors.md
for details about this error.
```

Comment: Can you post the line that caused the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tried mongo 2.4 text search via mongoid and bumped into the same issue as you. I've played a little bit with it and found the following solution. Here is how I've made it working

Example:

```
User.mongo_session.command(text: 'users', search: 'search string')
```

Here 'text' key should point to the collection name.

You will get Moped::BSON::Document that have information about found documents.
Hope it will help you as well

Comment: This is not working with Mongoid 4. I get the following error: failed with error 59: "no such command: 'text', bad cmd: '{ text: \"contacts\", search: \"something\" }'"

Answer (score 12):

For anyone finding this, Mongoid 4.0 allows for full text search like this:

```
Model.text_search('query')
```

You can chain as you normally would:

```
Listings.in(category: sections).where(listing_type: 'Website').text_search(params[:q]).to_a
```

Indexes are pretty easy as well:

```
index({name: "text", description: "text"}, {weights: {name: 10, description: 2}, name: "TextIndex"})
```

**EDIT: July 2017**

As reported below, text_search is deprecated.  I've been using where() like this:

Model.where('$text' => { '$search' => "\"#{params[:q]}\"" })

Comment: text_search is now deprecated

Comment: @mymlyn would have been nice to comment with the new method to use.

Comment: @mymlyn rather than telling us that this is no longer the solution, tell us what the solution actually is.

Answer (score 1):

Based on  Durran Jordan answer on a question about 'Mongo 2.4 full text search with Moped?' in this link: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongoid/hJRbaNMy6w4, I will suggest you change your command from:

```
 Article.mongo_session.command({:text => {:search => 'Ruby'}})
```

**to this:**

```
 Article.with(database: "text").mongo_session.command({:text => {:search => 'Ruby'}})
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this one worked.

Here 
Favorite.mongo_session.command(:text =>'table_name', search: 'search parameter')

Make sure the :text 's value is the table name and not the field.